# Mosaic Hop Issue

Tags: yeast, hops, malt

I'm trying to do some hop analysis based on a single hop IPA with some dry hopping on it.

I often drink some industrial beers simply based on Mosaic hop, and I do love it. But when i use it, it keeps me bringing so much passion fruit flavor and aroma, more than usual.

Is there some interaction with my malts chosen? I'm using carared, pilsen and melanoidin. Or it's related to the yeast (US-05)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're comparing to a beer produced in a brewery, it could be difference in types of hop used and freshness. Are you using whole hops or are you using pellets? Most homebrewers I know (myself included) use the hop pellets you get at your LHBS because they're the most available.

I could be wrong on this, but my understanding of hops besides whether they introduce bitterness or aroma into your beer, is independent on the type of malts or yeasts you use. The only thing I can think of that might affect hops and the flavour of your resulting beer is your water profile (tap water, bottled, filtered, etc) and its pH level.

Have you tried experimenting with the amount of hops you're using? If you're finding the hops are too strong, try reducing the amount. A general rule of thumb if you're using a new hop is to add in about 1-2 oz (28-56g) to a five gallon batch (19L) and work your way up or down from there.

Comment: Indeed, haven't wrote about water, but i did some gypsum addition on it. You're right, it's probably the water...

Comment: Dry-hopping is not the only way to instil aroma from hops. You could also try adding hops "late" in the boil (at flame out they will contribute virtually no bitterness, but only aroma). 

So anything added between 60min and 0min boil-time would add different flavours in between some bitterness and some aroma.

Comment: Indeed, i did both... late addition (10 min after flame is off) and DH...